# Cannot login to sites in web browser control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

We have a *WPF* application ,and using a web browser control in it, we are unable to login at certain sites (e.g. [this one](https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=in)) in the browser control.

I am able to open the login screen but even though using valid credential it is redirecting me to login page only with the WPF APP. But when I opened in the chrome or any other browser it works fine.

Is that a issue with browser control in *WPF* application?

Comment: Might have to do with iframes or javascript execution. Investigate how the login process of the affected sites works and see what the control supports.

Comment: Don't you have a cookie system? Don't you need to send a token in the http requests once you are logged?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is not answer but reply to users who given suggestions to us:-

@H.B:- We are using WPF not Iframe as IFrame will not allow to open other domain site into our domain as it voilate same origin policy.

@pix:- We don't have control on others site (these site not belong to us, it can be any site) login mechanism, here we are just trying to open other site into our WPF application's browser control,for most of site we able to login do the stuff but some of the sites are not allowing to login.

We debugged and found that once we login, it's try to navidate to other page of stie which is clearly visible (page name/ url) but then some thing happens and the site redirect it back to the login page once again.

Please let us know if you need some more inputs.